# И снова массив и foreach

Tags: php

Доброе время суток, как во второй цикл foreach запихнуть ['users']

```
if (!isset($all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]))
    $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]= array();
        $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['summs']+=(int)$ser_row['allmkad'];
            $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['rabota']+=(int)$ser_row['stafkaautoper'];
            $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'][] = $ser_row['cf_672'];
            $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['users'][] = $usernameauto;

foreach($all as $key => $ser) {
         if ($key == ''){
        } else {
        $resultss ='';
        foreach ($ser['dayes'] as $day) {
            $resultss .= $day;
        }
        $lislauto .= "<tr>
                <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" .$key."</td>
                <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" .$ser[rabota]. "</td></tr><tr><td>". $resultss ."</td></tr>";                  
            }
        }
```

Comment: 'stafkaautoper'

Comment: Подумал что будет кратко и понятно. Хочу что бы получилось как вывод  дерева первый цикл выводит ключ и итог, а второй цикл выводит что содержит ключ а именно вот это:
$all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['dayes'][] = $ser_row['cf_672']; $all[$ser_row['serialnumber']]['users'][] = $usernameauto;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**foreach** здесь совершенно не нужен.
Предлагаю такое решение:
**Правки**
Вместо

```
if ($key == '') {
} else
```

Я бы написал:

```
if (!empty($key)) {
}
```

А вместо

```
$resultss = '';
foreach ($ser['dayes'] as $day) {
    $resultss .= $day;
}
```

Вот это:

```
$results = implode('', $ser['dayes']);
//Вместо пустых кавычек можно вставить ', '
//Тогда даты будут выводиться вот так:
//24.10.2009, 24.12.2008, 21.04.2003 и т.д.
```

Учитывая эти правки вывод нужной тебе информации можно сделать вот так:

```
foreach ($all as $key => $ser) {
    if (!empty($key)) {
        $days = implode(', ', $ser['dayes']); //написал $days вместо $resultss
        $users = implode(', ', $ser['users']);
        //colspan нужен, потому что у тебя в первой строчке 2 столбца,
        //а в остальных по одному
        $lislauto .= "<tr>
                <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" . $key . "</td>
                <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" . $ser['rabota'] . "</td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan=\"2\">" . $days . "</td></tr>
                <tr><td colspan=\"2\">" . $users . "</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

Учитывая комментарий задавшего вопрос
**Вариант 2**

```
foreach ($all as $key => $ser) {
    if (!empty($key)) {
        $days = array_values($ser['dayes']);
        $users = array_values($ser['users']);
        $days_total = count($days);
        $users_total = count($users);
        $info = '';
        if ($days_total === $users_total) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < $days_total; ++$i) {
                $info .= "
                <tr>
                    <td>Число {$days[$i]}</td>
                    <td>Человек {$users[$i]}</td>
                    <td>Топливо {$ser['rastoplivo']}</td>
                    <td>Адрес {$ser['pereadres']}</td>
                    <td>Простой {$ser['prostoysverx']}</td>
                </tr>";
            }
        }
        $lislauto = "<tr>
                <td class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" . $key . "</td>
                <td colspan=\"4\" class=\"dvtCellLabel\">" . $ser['rabota'] . "</td></tr>
                " . $info;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, таким образом все данные выводятся одной строкой, они не изменят свой порядок вывода если по ним пройтись explode и построить табличку?

Comment: Приведи пример того, как должна выглядеть таблица (сверстай ее в html, заполнив столбцы фиктивными данными). Помогу построить в цикле.

Comment: <tr>
<td>Номер $key</td>
<td colspan="4">['rabota']</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Число ['dayes']</td>
<td>Человек ['users']</td>
<td>Топливо ['rastoplivo']</td>
<td>Адрес ['pereadres']</td>
<td>Простой ['prostoysverx']</td>
</tr>

Comment: У тебя одинаковое количество элементов в массиве **$ser['dayes']** и **$ser['users']**? Тогда смотри **Вариант 2** в решении. Но что-то мне подсказывает, что ты изначально неправильно массив формируешь и просто не то спрашиваешь.

Comment: Да одинаковое, возможно ты и прав, столкнулся с массивами пару дней назад вот учусь ) Спасибо тебе большое! могу скинуть код формирования массива глянешь, что не так )